# How to Change a cin Input to a Command Line Argument Input in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to change my code from asking for a cin user input of x and y values to using a single command line argument with the name of a file. The file has a series of doubles for x and y, one pair on each line separated by a space. I understand how to write the code like I did here, but when it comes to command line arguments, I get confused. If anyone could offer any tips or help in converting the code, I would be very appreciative.

```
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <vector>
3 #include <cmath>
4 
5 using namespace std;
6 
7 double correlation_r(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y);
8 double mean(const vector<double> &x_obs);
9 double st_dev(const vector<double> &x_obs);
10 void least_squares_regression(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y);
11 
12 int main(){
13     
14     double x;
15     double y;
16     vector<double> x_obs;
17     vector<double> y_obs;
18     
19     cout << "Please enter two real number values for x and y: ";
20     
21     while(cin >> x >> y){
22         if (!cin.good()){
23             break;
24         } else {
25             x_obs.push_back(x);
26             y_obs.push_back(y);
27             
28             cout << "Please enter two real number values for x and y or a string to terminate: ";
29         }
30     }
31     
32     if(x_obs.size()==0||x_obs.size()==1){
33         cout << "The sample was too small to be useful.";
34         return 0;
35     }
36     
37     cout << "The sample mean of x is " << mean(x_obs) << endl;
38     cout << "The sample mean of y is " << mean(y_obs) << endl;
39     
40     cout << "The sample standard deviation of x is " << st_dev(x_obs) << endl;
41     cout << "The sample standard deviation of y is " << st_dev(y_obs) << endl;
42     
43     if(st_dev(x_obs)==0.0){
44         cout << "The correlation is undefined." << endl;
45     } else if(st_dev(y_obs)==0.0&& st_dev(x_obs)!=0.0){
46         cout << "The correlation is undefined." << endl;
47     } else {
48         cout << "The sample correlation is " << correlation_r(x_obs, y_obs) << endl;
49     }
50     
51 
52     least_squares_regression(x_obs, y_obs);
53     
54     return 0;
55 }
56 void least_squares_regression(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y){
57 double m;
58 double b;
59 if(st_dev(x)!=0 && st_dev(y)!=0){
60  m=correlation_r(x,y)*(st_dev(y)/st_dev(x));
61  b= mean(y)-(m*mean(x));
62  cout << "The least squares regression line is y=" << m << "x+ " << b << endl;
63 } else if(st_dev(x)==0){
64  cout<< "The least squares linear regression line is undefined."<< endl;
65 } else if(st_dev(y)==0 && st_dev(x)!=0){
66  cout<< "The least squares linear regression line is y=" << mean(y) << endl;
67 }
68 return;
69 }
70  
71
72 double correlation_r(const vector<double> &x, const vector<double> &y){
73 double r = 0.0;
74 for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
75     r += (x[i] - mean(x))*(y[i] - mean(y))/st_dev(x)/st_dev(y);
76 }
77 return r = r / (x.size() - 1.0);
78 }
79
80
81 double mean(const vector<double> &x_obs){
82 double total = 0.0;
83 for (int i = 0; i < x_obs.size(); i++){
84  total += x_obs[i];
85 }    
86 return total/x_obs.size();
87 }
88
89 double st_dev(const vector<double> &x_obs){
90 double x_bar = mean(x_obs);
91 double total = 0.0;
92 for (double elem : x_obs){
93  total += pow(elem - x_bar, 2);
94 }
95 return pow( total/(x_obs.size() - 1.0), .5);
96 }
```

Comment: Recommendation: don't put in line numbers. It makes it harder to compile your code if we out here need to compile the code to get a closer look at the problem. If a line is important, add a comment (like "The error is right here!!!!") to it to draw attention to it.

Comment: Fun fact: if `while(cin >> x >> y)` fails, the `wile` loop will not be entered, making `if (!cin.good())` redundant. If the stream's not good, you never get there.

Comment: Side note: `pow` is designed to handle really nasty stuff like e to the power of pi. It can be vast overkill for squaring a number. `y = x * x;` is almost always faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your main definition to

`int main(int argc, char ** argv)`

`argc` "Argument count" is the number of arguments, separated by whitespaces, you passed to your program

`argv` "Argument value" is an array of c strings which hold your arguments. `argv[0]` is always yor calling programs path.

So to do what you want to achieve, change your main and take the command line arguments to create a `fstream` or `ifstream` object which acts pretty much like your standard `istream` friend `cin` just that it reads from files instead of `stdin`

EDIT:
I should say that you can not overload your main as you please but that these are the two signatures for the standard main procedure there are.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got that far, but how do I actually get the program to read the file characters as my x and y inputs and ignore the spaces and all?

Comment: @Kaleigh Simply create an `ifstream` that opens the file, and then call `operator>>` on that stream to read your values as needed, eg: `ifstream fs(filename); while (fs >> x >> y) { ... }` Just like you originally did to read values from `cin`: `while (cin >> x >> y)`.  `operator>>` works on ANY kind of `istream`-based stream.  Also, you don't need to use `if (!good()){ break; }` inside your loop, as the stream will be in an error state that breaks the `while` statement if `operator>>` fails to read a value, so `good()` will ALWAYS be true at the top of each loop iteration.